# Material Design Lite - aligning the hamburger (drawer) menu with the items in the header bar

Tags: material-design-lite

How can I horinzontally align the hamburger (drawer) menu with the rest of the items in the header bar? So, moving the hamburger menu to the drawn red bar.

[image]

The code is:

```
<body>
  <div class="mdl-layout mdl-js-layout mdl-layout--fixed-header">
  <header class="mdl-layout__header">
    <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
      <span class="mdl-layout-title">Acme</span>
      <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
      <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Home</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">About</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Contact</a>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </header>
    <div id="mydrawer" class="mdl-layout__drawer">
    <span class="mdl-layout-title">Acme</span>
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Products</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Services</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Portfolios</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Achievements</a>
      <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="#">Blog</a>
    </nav>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Which one are you using https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#menus-section

Comment: Lower left. Above is all the code. I simplified the example. The result is in all situations that the hamburger menu is not aligned, too high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is on the very first line of my html page. Put the next line **before** the first **<html>** tag:

```
<!doctype html>
```